# PSScriptAnalyzer checking for PSCredential type

Tags: powershell

I have installed the static PowerShell code analyzer [PSScriptAnalyzer](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer). The readme states:

"Analyzer checks for the presence of uninitialized variables, usage of **PSCredential** **Type**, usage of Invoke-Expression etc."

What is the purpose of checking for a `[pscredential]` type. Shoud `[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]` be used instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[pscredential]` is just a type accelerator for `[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]`.

It's in other words the same thing and you can verify this by running `[PSCredential].FullName` and
`[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential].FullName`.

So when they say it checks for **PSCredential Type** they actually mean the latter. The check is to make sure it's not a regular string (and on that note, you could also compare `[System.String]` and `[string]`) but a proper type for the task.